# how to install visual studo community edition 2019 on arch linux

Tags: installation, arch-linux, visual-studio

So i'm on arch linux and have just started unity. Now with unity, it is recommended to install visual studio community edition but I cant seem to find a way to do this. Everywhere on the internet it just shows vscode but not visual studio.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Visual Studio is only available for Windows and Apple: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/de/

Comment: If Linux, you are going to need a Windows VM.  The windows version is nothing like the apple version and you can't legally run that in a vm anyways.

Comment: Oh ok thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Visual Studio Community *doesn't support on Linux plataform*, only Windows one.

These are the Visual Studio Community requeriments:

> *Supported Operating Systems*
>
> *X64 Visual Studio 2022 is supported on the following x64-bit operating systems:*
>
> - *Windows 11 version 21H2 or higher: Home, Pro, Pro Education, Pro for Workstations, Enterprise, and Education*
> - *Windows 10 version 1909 or higher: Home, Professional, Education, and Enterprise.*
> - *Windows Server 2022: Standard and Datacenter.*
> - *Windows Server 2019: Standard and Datacenter.*
> - *Windows Server 2016: Standard and Datacenter.*
>
> *Arm64 Visual Studio 2022 17.4 and later are supported on the following 64-bit ARM operating systems:*
>
> - *Windows 11 version 21H2 or higher*

*But you could run Visual Studio Community in a virtual machine with Windows installed. That'd be a good alternative for solving your issue.*

References:

- [Visual Studio 2022 Product Family System Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/system-requirements)